# NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, oozie

I am trying to install oozie and getting this error.I have hadoop 2.7.1, maven 3.3.3 .Any suggestion on this?

> huseyin@ubuntu:~$
>   '/usr/local/oozie/oozie/Oozie/oozie-4.3.0-SNAPSHOT/bin/oozie-setup.sh'
>   sharelib create -fs hdfs://hadoopcluster:10000    setting
>   CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xmx1024m"
>
> Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and
>   try again Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration  at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)    at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)    at
>   java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)   at
>   java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)    at
>   sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
>     at
>   sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 7 more

Comment: Why focus blindly on the JNI keyword? the `NoClassDefFoundError` is quite explicit: check the CLASSPATH to see if the Hadoop libs are in there...

Answer (score 3):

You need to add all the needed jars for oozie to a new folder in your working directory (oozie-4.3.0-SNAPSHOT) called libext , please check the following paragraph from [oozie docs](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/DG_QuickStart.html#Building_Oozie)

> By default, oozie war will not contain hadoop and hcatalog libraries,
>   however they are required for oozie to work.
>
> There are 2 options to add these libraries:
>
> 1. At install time, copy the hadoop and hcatalog libraries to libext and run oozie-setup.sh to setup oozie war.
> 2. Build with -Puber which will bundle the required libraries in the oozie war.

so to solve the problem you need to :

1- Create a libext/ directory in the directory where Oozie was expanded.

2- If using the ExtJS library copy the ZIP file to the libext/ directory.

3- If hadoop and hcatalog libraries are not already included in the war, add the corresponding libraries to libext/ directory. (In your case ) ,  you can just copy all the jars from your hadoop project project to the libext folder.

**Important Note** : the versions of the jars inside the libext folder should match the versions of those installed during the build process.

You can find the versions of the ones downloaded in the pom file you used during the build process.

Answer (score -1):

```
cp  $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/**/*.jar libext/
cp  $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/common/*.jar libext/
cp  $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/common/lib/*.jar libext/
cp  $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*.jar libext/ 
cp  $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/*.jar libext/
cp  $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*.jar libext/
cp  $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*.jar libext/
cp  $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*.jar libext/
cp  $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn/*.jar libext/
```